# Help, I changed my icons with Tweaks, now nothing works

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

I tried to change the icons to the Colloid icon pack with GnomeTweaks. However, now all the icons are gone, and Tweaks doesn't open. What can I do? The only thing I can do is open Chrome, the Files and Terminal won't even open.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJuYh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your icon theme as follows:

1. Open a terminal
2. Issue following command:

   ```
   gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
   ```

If that does not help, then try resetting all settings related to Gnome Desktop to factory default with the command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer. That also shows other users a usefull answer can be found here